# how to display properly and 2x2 array with 0,0 just like in grid?

Tags: java, matrix, multidimensional-array, grid

how can i create an 2x2 array just like the one in the bottom. Take note that the coordinate 0,0 is at the bottom left.

```
(0,2) (1,2) (2,2)
(0,1) (1,1) (2,1) 
(0,0) (1,0) (2,0)
```

Currently

im using something like this:

```
int[][] matrix = new int[width][height];
    for (int x = 0; x < matrix.length; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < matrix[x].length; y++) {
//println
    }}
```

but when i try to access the data the coordinates are as follows:

```
(0,0) (1,0) (2,0)
(0,1) (1,1) (2,1)
(0,2) (1,2) (2,2)
```

your help is deeply appreciated.

Comment: Your desired and current order makes no sense, multiple elements are listed twice or even 3 times like `(1,2)`.

Comment: Your code shows something like:
`(0,0) (0,1) (0,2) 
(1,0) (1,1) (1,2) 
(2,0) (2,1) (2,2) `
Even the desired matrix isn't making some pattern.

Comment: updated the values in my 1st post. sorry for the scrambled value.

Comment: If you feel that my answer helped you, you could accept my answer. That does two things. It lets everyone know your issue has been resolved to your satisfaction, and it gives the person that helps you credit for the assist. [See here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) for a full explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate over the inner array in reverse order first to achieve the desired ordering:

```
int[][] matrix = new int[width][height];
for (int y = height - 1; y >= 0; y--) {
    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
        System.out.print(matrix[x][y] + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```